# Can we connect to any version of oracle using cx_oracle library python?

Tags: database, oracle, python-3.5, cx-oracle

I am trying to write a script to connect to all version's of oracle database starting from the latest to the oldest version of database.

I tried myself with cx_oracle library found like it needs a client library in the local to connect to remote database like if I download the latest version then it will work up to latest few versions not all.

Also tried with Sqlalchemy connection which is also using cx_oracle libraries.

Please do guide me if am doing anything wrong? I would also like to hear if there are any other ways to connect to the database using **PYTHON**

Answer (score 1):

cx_Oracle 6 and higher already support connecting to any Oracle database from 9i all the way up to 18c depending on the client that you are using. cx_Oracle requires Oracle Client libraries at least at 11.2. You can see the interoperability notes [here](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#oracle-client-and-oracle-database-interoperability). Since anything earlier than 11.2 is no longer supported anyway, that should be adequate in almost all circumstances.

You can also use ODBC to connect to the database but that won't perform as well as cx_Oracle does.

Comment: So if i use a client for 18c or 12c we can access database from 9i to 18c right

Comment: Not quite. 18c client allows you to connect to 11.2 databases. An 11.2 client will allow you to connect from 9i to 18c. Of course when connecting to higher versioned databases you won't be able to take advantage of the new features that are available in those versions!

Comment: I got it like 11.2 insta_client libraries can be used to 9i to 18c  . I will test it and will come back

Answer (score 0):

I have an 11.2 Oracle database client on my corporate Windows 7 laptop and use cx_Oracle to connect to databases from version 9.2 to 12.2 without any difficulty.

The other way I connect to databases of all versions is to wrap Python around the Linux version of Oracle's sqlplus utility. This way I do not need to install cx_Oracle and can run with an older Oracle client and the version of Python that comes with the Linux distribution. In my case I am running on Redhat 6 which comes with Python 2.6. I connect to databases from version 8.1 to 12.2 in this way.

I have a blog post about how I run sqlplus from Python on Linux: https://www.bobbydurrettdba.com/2016/11/04/running-sqlplus-from-a-python-script/

Bobby